# Working with Array... cannot figure out the error

Tags: c, arrays

Question: Write a function IndexOf that, given a string s and a character c, returns the position of the first occurrence of c in s. If c  is not in s, return -1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char name = "Elham";
    char alph= 'a';
    printf("%d", IndexOf(name,alph));
}

int IndexOf(char s[], char c){

    int h = 0;

    while ( s[h] != '\0'){
        if (s[h] == c)
            return h;
        else if(s[h] == '\0')
            return -1;
        else 
            // Do nothing
        h++;
    }
}
```

ERROR: On line 8: 8 [Note] an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration

Comment: Which error?  Provide expected & actual outputs and/or error messages.

Comment: On line 8: 8 [Note] an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration

Comment: Good. Now [edit] your question to add that, comments don't count here.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using but GCC doesn't show me *that* Note you mentioned in your question, compiling your same code. Btw I even didn't get it at all, it could be just nothing.

Comment: Don't edit the question once the answer is posted ..Hope someone comes along and Rollback the edits.

Comment: @user2728397 - as long as the edits don't change the core meaning of the question they are welcome.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You right, may be i have not observed it, but the statement in question `char name[] = "Elham";` is changed  from `char name = "Elham";` and many answers suggesting not to use it.

Comment: You're right, I missed that in the cloud of formatting edits. Restored the original.

Comment: Ok guys!! I am new, hope I learn soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what error you are getting. But I see these problems:

1. The declaration `char name = "Elham";` is incorrect. It should be
   `char *name = "Elham";`
2. The `if` condition in your code is missing parentheses.

`if s[h] == '\0' return -1;`

should be:

`if (s[h] == '\0') return -1;`

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, it helped to an extend

Comment: cant believe I am making such mistakes..... SO OBVIOSE

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign a string to `char` data type.

Change this line

```
char name = "Elham";
```

to

```
char* name = "Elham";
```

Now you should do this.

```
while ( s[h] != '\0'){
    if (s[h] == c) 
       return h;
    else if(s[h] == '\0')
        return -1;
    h++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand the answers, a couple of tips:

1) Your version is limited to modifiable strings, use `const char *` in order to accept any (`const` and non-const) string.

2) Make use of the (optimized) functions of the standard library, in this case [strchr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int IndexOf(const char *str, int chr)
{
    const char *ptr;

    return (ptr = strchr(str, chr)) ? (int)(ptr - str) : -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char name[] = "Elham";
    char alph = 'a';

    printf("%d\n", IndexOf(name, alph));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: His homework is to write that function himself, so without use of optimized library functions, I assume.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, well ... even if this is a homework, you can give some tip for the real world, isn't it? ;)

Comment: ...yes,...in addition to showing where he was wrong in his solution, so he learns?

Comment: ... _"Just to expand the answers"_ must tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is ok. The error is in the `main()` function.
  The variable `name` must be a `char[]`, not a `char`.

Correct code: `char name[] = "Elham";`

Comment: thanks, it helped. though the main error I am not understanding is this:

Comment: On line 8: 8 [Note] an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration –

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you posted wrong, but I think you meant this

```
char *name = "Elham";
```

insted of

```
char name = "Elham";
```

Comment: What's the point of the cast? Why not make `name` a `const char *`? Modifying string literals is undefined.

Comment: Bad habit, I use `g++` more frequently, that's why the cast.

Comment: I use g++ all the time and have never needed to cast a string literal to a `char *`.

Comment: May be you are the one who just doesn't care about "warnings". @Downvoter

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `char[]` to `char *`, so a cast is completely superfluous. There isn't going to be any warning. You edited the question according to my comment yourself, so I figure you get my meaning.

Comment: See for yourself : `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  char *a = "a";` And I removed the cast because the OP is coding in C, not C++. @Downvoter

Comment: As you say, this question is about C. That means *there is not going to be any warning*. C++ string literals are arrays of `const char`, so initializing a `char *` with a string literal is forbidden. You use `const char *` (or commonly `std::string` in C++) to prevent undefined behavior and comply with the standard as I suggested to you in my [very first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186266/working-with-array-cannot-figure-out-the-error/42186299?noredirect=1#comment71534805_42186299). `char *str = "literal"` is just bad C code and invalid C++ code.